# Accessing method from controller in a Bootstrap Modal with Laravel 5

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5

I want to access a method from a controller in Laravel 5.

I can access a method in a simple view but not in a loaded Bootstrap modal.

This is my code from the modal:

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="title_modal">Persoon aanmaken: <strong><?php echo $_GET["functie"];
                ?></strong></h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
                    <?php
                    $user = \App\Http\Controllers\PersonController::getPerson();
                    print_r($user);
                    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary send-btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" /> Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Error message while using it in a Bootstrap Modal:

> Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PersonController' not found in *"Path of modal"*

Can someone help me out?

Comment: I think, we need to see the Modal. Otherwise can't tell

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha I've added my modal code to the question

Comment: How are you loading this modal on the page?  Is it an external PHP file which you are are calling?

Comment: @user3158900 Yes it is, the modal is a seperate php file with only the modal code. I think there is something wrong with that because I can't acces anything from Laravel

Comment: Yeah, because it's not loading up Laravel.  Add another route to Laravel and a controller function and have it return a view with this code in it, and then set the URL of the modal to your new Laravel route.

Comment: @user3158900 yes this helped me out. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want get current user you can use Auth facade

```
<?php $user = Auth::user(); ?>
```

Or call controller action

```
<?php $user = app('App\Http\Controllers\PersonController')->getPerson(); ?>
```

Comment: Now I get a Fatal error : "Fatal error: Call to undefined function app() in..."

Comment: How you render this Modal html ?

Comment: I render it from a seperate php file, I think there is something wrong with that because I can't acces anything from Laravel

Comment: Yes, just create a simple route what render view with this html.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it